# Delete rows with duplicate value in one column but different value in another column

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-error-1064, duplicates, delete-row

I have a table in MariaDB 5.5 that looks like this:

```
| PRODUCT_ID | STORE_ID |
-------------------------
|        111 |        0 |
|        111 |        1 |
|        112 |        0 |
|        112 |        1 |
|        113 |        0 |
|        114 |        1 |
|        115 |        1 |
|        116 |        0 |
|        117 |        0 |
|        117 |        1 |
```

What I want to do is to delete all duplicate rows by column product_id where value by store_id is 0 so the final table would look like this:

```
| PRODUCT_ID | STORE_ID |
-------------------------
|        111 |        1 |
|        112 |        1 |
|        113 |        0 |
|        114 |        1 |
|        115 |        1 |
|        116 |        0 |
|        117 |        1 |
```

This sql query returns all duplicate entries by column product_id:

```
SELECT `product_id` FROM `table` GROUP BY `product_id` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

so I tried this one:

```
DELETE FROM `table` AS a WHERE a.`store_id` = '0' AND a.`product_id` IN (SELECT b.`product_id` FROM  `table` AS b GROUP BY b.`product_id` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

but it gives me an error in sql syntax:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS a WHERE a.`store_id` = '0' AND a.`product_id` IN (SELECT b.`product_id` FROM ' at line 1

What's the reason of this error and what query should I use instead?

Comment: To be clear, can you construct a query that returns only those rows selected for deletion (or, conversely, only those rows selected to remain).

Comment: Do you have any Primary key in this table?

Comment: Not sure about MariaDB but for mysql see this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, I can construct query that returns only those rows selected for deletion<br />

SELECT \`product_id\` FROM \`table\` WHERE \`store_id\` = '0' AND \`product_id\` IN (SELECT \`product_id\` FROM \`table\` GROUP BY \`product_id\` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

Comment: @valex No, I don't use Primary key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will delete all rows that have STORE_ID=0 and that are duplicated:

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM
  yourtable t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT PRODUCT_ID
                           FROM yourtable
                           GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
                           HAVING COUNT(*)>1) t2
  ON t1.PRODUCT_ID = t2.PRODUCT_ID
     AND t1.STORE_ID=0;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1187/1).